# Two finger swipe for back/forward navigation in web browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, touchpad

I'm trying to get 2 finger horizontal swipe on my touchpad to navigate back/forward in a web browser (Ubuntu). This features is standard in Windows and Mac, yet seems to be impossible on Linux.

Is it possible to get this working with a 2 finger swipe?

Comment: does the input driver you are using support two-finger gestures at all? Same browser as on Mac and Windows?

Comment: Yes it works on the same machine on Windows 11, Chrome. Doesn't work on Ubuntu in Chrome or Firefox.